# Cannot figure out why JS complains that object is undefined

Tags: javascript

I get the following error when I try to push an object to an array.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.setTimes

...but afaik, the property of push (times) is defined. So what is the problem? 
Here is my code

```
let timeDB = {
  mon: [],
  tue: [],
  wed: [],
  thu: [],
  fri: [],
  sat: [],
  sun: []
};

// Save times to database
let setTimes = function(){
  let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('timeContainer'); 
  //console.log(inputs);
  for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    let day = inputs[i].parentNode.id;
    //console.log(day);
    let times = {
      start: inputs[i].childNodes[0].value,
      end: inputs[i].childNodes[1].value
    };
    console.log(times);
    timeDB.day.push(times);
    //console.log(inputs[i].parentNode.id + " " + "start time: " + inputs[i].childNodes[0].value);
    //console.log(inputs[i].parentNode.id + " " + "end time: " + inputs[i].childNodes[1].value);
    //console.log(inputs[i].parentNode.id);
  }
};

let saveButton = document.getElementById("saveTimes").addEventListener( 'click', setTimes );
```

Here is the full [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/zdu96p7q/)

Thanks

Comment: timeDB.day is not defined but timesDB.mon

Comment: try timeDB[day].push(times);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use : `timeDB[day].push(times);`

Comment: Ok, thanks. It worked! I have no idea why, but it did.

Comment: Oh, reading a previous comment, I see now what is going on. I can't use `day` in the context of an object property key like I did.